# CQRS read model side - normalized tables

Tags: cqrs

I have been reading about Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) and how this pattern would suit our current applications.

When it comes to the read model I am well aware of the concepts:
"separating read and write data model", "flat denormalized data returned by the thin read layer". In most cases we are stuck with the same database(the same read/write data model), running on SQL Server with normalized tables, with common layered application on top of it.

So, is it any value of applying CQRS on this kind of scenario?
If so, what would it be when it comes to the read model side?

Another question that hits my mind is MVC application requesting information from my thin read layer that expose flattened out views. Data exposed still need to be structured(aggragated) before presented to the user, or am I wrong?

Best regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CQRS doesn't need to have a flattened read model; that is a benefit that CQRS can allow you to provide, but it is neither required nor a key part of the approach.

CQRS is about separation (or segregation if you follow the name).  It is the Command Query Separation principle on steroid (in my opinion).  The benefits that it provides you (off the top of my head) are:

- separation of your read operations from your write operations;
- communication between layers via messaging (e.g. commands, events), so that your layers are clean;
- separation within your layers, applying the Single Responsibility Principle (e.g. your domain applies business logic, your command handles route commands, your denormalizers or event handlers (or whatever you call them) persist information to your read store, etc.)
- allows you to have team members work on different parts of your application without hard dependencies between them;
- etc.

So if those things above are important to you or something you want to strive for (and your application's design supports implementing CQRS), then CQRS provides benefit and value to you.

There are many benefits to CQRS.  It's not the right solution for every problem, but when the stars align, it's a nice approach to your problem (even if you don't have a denormalized read store, or an event store, or an async model, etc.).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I've fought with multiple joins so many times in my career that when a structure like CQRS and ES comes along and offers a clean way to simplify the read side, I jumped at it. The nice thing is that you can get many of the benefits without necessarily implementing all the elements often associated with CQRS and ES. Just separating command from queries has the benefit of simplifying your code. However, when you do start using a de-normaliser to build out read models for you application you suddenly realise how simple, clean and performant your app can be.

If it helps to see 'how' this de-normalisation works take a look at this post (it comes with a code sample to take a gander at): [How to build a master details view with CQRS and ES](http://danielwhittaker.me/2014/10/05/build-master-details-view-using-cqrs-event-sourcing/). I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Applying CQRS over the same (say) third normal form database can still give you value on the read side if it allows you to stop projecting read models from domain objects.

This also allows you to better specialise your domain to (I assume) transaction processing, meaning many relationships may not be necessary.